# Compiling qml files into rcc files in CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qtquick2

I want to make a Qt Quick project using CMake with compiled qml files. I put my QML files into a separate qrc/rcc file in a cmake projekt:

`qt5_add_binary_resources("res" "qml.qrc" DESTINATION "qml.rcc")`

This works fine so far. Now I wanted to compile them. According to the documentation I only need to change

`qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)
add_executable(myapp ${SRC_LIST} ${RESOURCES)`

to

`find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)
add_executable(myapp ${SRC_LIST} ${RESOURCES)`

in a project. So I changed my CMakeLists.txt to

`find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources("QML_RESOURCE" "qml.qrc")
qt5_add_binary_resources("res" ${QML_RESOURCE} DESTINATION "qml.rcc")`

But now I get

`FAILED: qml.rcc cmd.exe /C "cd /D "D:\buildPath" && C:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2017_64\bin\rcc.exe --binary --name res --output qml.rcc "D:/buildPath/main_qml.cpp" "D:/buildPath/qmlcache_loader.cpp""`

`RCC Parse Error: 'D:/buildPath/main_qml.cpp' Line: 1 Column: 1 [Start tag expected.] [2/4 30.3/sec] Automatic MOC for target PROJECT_NAME ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

`17:10:39: The process "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 1. Error while building/deploying project PROJECT_NAME (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.3 MSVC2017 64bit) When executing step "Build with CMake"`

There isn't much information about Qt and CMake, so I don't know what to do about this. I hope someone can give me some advice.

The full working CMakeLists is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(QtQuickCompiler LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES qml.qrc)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" ${RESOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)
```

The full not working file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(QtQuickCompiler LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES qml.qrc)
qt5_add_binary_resources(qml ${RESOURCES} DESTINATION "qml.rcc")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)
```

This was created using the template projects provided by QtCreator.

Comment: Something is out of order. RCC is attempting to parse `main_qml.cpp` as an XML file (evidenced by the error `[Start tag expected.]`), but this should not be happening. Can you post your entire CMake file?

Comment: @Thorsten Schmitz, did you figure out what was going wrong?